# Getting datepicker to work with JavaScript date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker

I have an object with a date property `vm.SomeDate` in the following format:

```
2012-10-12T00:00:00
```

In my Angular app, I then have an input field with `type="date"`

```
<input type="date" ng-model="vm.SomeDate">
```

This doesn't work out of the box though, it just shows me a datepicker with an empty date, `dd.mm.yyyy`. I have tried various filters such a `vm.SomeDate | date:'YYYY.MM.yyyy`, but they don't seem to help at all.

How can I get the datepicker working with this date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a `Date` object as a model to the `<input>`. If `vm.SomeDate` is a string, you can use it as a constructor argument:

```
new Date($scope.vm.SomeDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-ddT00:00:00"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class='selector' >
```